# Visibility of Editext Not Working in my dialogue in android

Tags: android, layout, dialog, android-edittext, visibility

Edittext Visibility not working in dialogue in my code here is my xml.

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radiorefus"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
                android:text="Outlet has refused to offer discount"
              />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioother"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Other" />
        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:hint="Enter short reason..."
        android:id="@+id/txtreport"
       android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Here my dialogue code dialogue will show on click of button.

```
     Dialog dialog = new Dialog(DetailOfListCard.this);
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.reportdialouge);
                    dialog.show();
 inflater = LayoutInflater.from(DetailOfListCard.this);
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reportdialouge, null);
                editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtreport);
                textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.reptxt);
```

Here I am using radio button on my dialogue layout.
 Here my java code where I want to set visibility to edit text on the basis of radio button

```
 public void onRadioButtonClicked(View v){
        RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup)view.findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
         radioButton = (RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.radiorefus);
         radioButton1 = (RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.radioother);

        // Is the current Radio Button checked?
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) v).isChecked();

        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.radiorefus:
                Toast.makeText(DetailOfListCard.this,"detail of list",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                break;

            case R.id.radioother:
               textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(DetailOfListCard.this,"edit text visible",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `radioButton = (RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.radiorefus);` replace this to  `radioButton = (RadioButton)dialog .findViewById(R.id.radiorefus);`

Comment: Where did you initialize `textView` and whats `view`?

Comment: initialise text viewfirst

Comment: I have initialized already please see post again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

intialize the edittext with your dialog like this,

```
EditText et= dialog.findViewById(R.id.edittext);
```

than , make your edittext visible like this,

```
et.setVisibility(VIEW.VISIBLE);
```